# FadeToggle/SlideToggle only works once

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a navigation drawer that fades out/fades in when clicked. In the jQuery code, I had made the navigation hide on load and when I click on the burger icon it fades in. However when I click on it again, it doesn't fade out.

I've had similar problems with the 'click' function before (in that the event takes place only the first time it was clicked) and I still can't figure out. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#topnav ul').hide()
  $('#burger').click(function() {
    $('#topnav ul').fadeToggle(300);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="title">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxfornav">

  <nav id="topnav">   
    <label id="burger" for="checkboxfornav">
      <div id="topline"></div>
      <div id="midline"></div>
      <div id="botline"></div>
    </label>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="works" href="#">Works</a></li>
      <li><a class="news" href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Firstly the `#burger` element has no content so nothing will appear to click on. If you add content, then the `ul` fades in and out on each successive click - which is the expected behaviour here. You say that you want the `ul` to fade out, but when should it do this?

Comment: It's work fine if you click on **label**, I edit your post and add **burger** for text of label

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yvg6kn7t/

Comment: The above link is to the Jsfiddle. The jquery code is located at the most bottom of the library. After it fades in, it doesnt fade out anymore.

Comment: @Levin Cause your overlay is over all others elements and you can't click on the hamburger after that.

Answer (score 4):

First the event listener was not on the `checkbox`, and when you put it on the `checkbox` the `fadeToggle` works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#topnav ul').hide()
  $('#checkboxfornav').change(function() {
       $('#topnav ul').fadeToggle($(this).is(":checked"));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="title">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxfornav">

  <nav id="topnav">   
    <label id="burger" for="checkboxfornav">
      <div id="topline"></div>
      <div id="midline"></div>
      <div id="botline"></div>
    </label>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="works" href="#">Works</a></li>
      <li><a class="news" href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your answers were helpful! It was my own mistake lol. When the navigation fades in, it covers over my #burger(the navigation was was not fully opaque.) After playing around with the z-index, I managed to solve it. Thank you so much!